# Efficient use of GatherBy on large list to remove duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization

I have a large nested list of rules, wherein elements which have repeated entries on the LHS of the rules should be deleted. For instance

`lis:={{a1 -> x1, a2 -> x2, a3 -> x3}, {b1 -> y1, b1 -> y2}}`

with

`GatherBy[#, #[[1]] &][[All, 1]] & /@ lis`

gives the desired output

`{{a1 -> x1, a2 -> x2, a3 -> x3}, {b1 -> y1}}`

However, this obviously takes a while to perform if the list is large, since I am iterating through the list. I tried a few things using Sow and Reap without much success.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `DeleteDuplicates` for this?

Answer (score 9):

If you want rules without duplicate keys, you really should be using Associations instead of lists of rules. They're much faster and automatically handle key duplicates. In this case, you could do:

```
Map[Normal @ Reverse @ Association[Reverse[#]]&, lis]
```

Remove the `Normal` if you want to stick with Associations (which I recommend). Note also that this is generally faster than `DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]`.

Comment: (+1) Nice, Sjoerd! :-)

Comment: Great thanks! I didn't know that about ```Associations```. This seems to be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
Map[DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]] @ lis
```

> ```
> {{a1 -> x1, a2 -> x2, a3 -> x3}, {b1 -> y1}}
> ```